# How to compare metrices in terms of RELATIVE bootstrap confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, bootstrap, coefficient-of-variation

**Situation**: We are assessing several metrices to compare two distributions (e.g. ttest-pvalue, Wasserstein distance, binary classification metrices like ROC-AUC, etc.). One criteria should be the "robustness" of a metric against population changes.

**Solution approach**: Calculate a confidence interval using bootstrapping. Then calculate a quasi-coefficient of variation as `|high-low|/mean`.

**Problem**: I don't feel like this quasi-coefficient of variation is a good indicator. It becomes very large for small mean values (e.g. pvalue or sensitivity-value at high specificities). Unfortunately I couldn't think of a better one so far. Would you have an idea?